# Best approach to insert delta records from view into a table

Tags: sql, hana

I have a requirement where I do a daily load from a view to a table. After the initial load, there may be scenarios where the original records get deleted from the view's source table. There are also scenarios where these records are updated.

When the stored procedure is run, the table that is loaded should pick up delta records. This means only new inserts. Also, it should mark deleted lines as D. In addition to this, any updates in source data must also updated in this table and marked as U.
Please refer to the attached image which shows in case 1 , 2 inserts on the initial load and then an update and then a delete. 
Left side represents the view and right side represents the table I am trying to load.
[image: Click for attached image]
Thanks!

Shyam

Comment: You tagged OP `sql-server`. Read about `merge` query.

Comment: Why not just use a view versus doing these updates

Comment: is it mysql or sql-server? tag only relevant information else it may be complicated

Comment: What DBMS do you use? You marked three different systems. Is there any relationship between view and this table?

Comment: If it is SQL Server you need to use triggers on a table, on which this view is based. You can use trigger on the view ONLY if insert/update/delete operations are used on this view.

Comment: Sorry id the tags caused confusion. I am on a SAP HANA DB. I am using SQL to write the code. I was looking for the logic more than the actual syntax itself and that's why I tagged multiple systems. I've removed the unwanted tags. Triggers are not an option here. I can only read from the view and write to the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use triggers on HANA database tables you can use following samples on a column table, if you are working with row tables then you can prefer statement based approach

```
create trigger Salary_A_DEL after DELETE on Salary
REFERENCING OLD ROW myoldrow
FOR EACH ROW
begin

INSERT INTO SalaryLog (
    Employee,
    Salary,
    Operation,
    DateTime
) VALUES (
    :myoldrow.Employee, 
    :myoldrow.Salary,
    'D',
    CURRENT_DATE
);

end;



create trigger Salary_A_UPD after UPDATE on Salary
REFERENCING NEW ROW mynewrow, OLD ROW myoldrow
FOR EACH ROW
begin

INSERT INTO SalaryLog (
    Employee,
    Salary,
    Operation,
    DateTime
) VALUES (
    :mynewrow.Employee, 
    :mynewrow.Salary,
    'U',
    CURRENT_DATE
);

end;



create trigger Salary_A_INS after INSERT on Salary
REFERENCING NEW ROW mynewrow
FOR EACH ROW
begin

INSERT INTO SalaryLog (
    Employee,
    Salary,
    Operation,
    DateTime
) VALUES (
    :mynewrow.Employee, 
    :mynewrow.Salary,
    'I',
    CURRENT_DATE
);

end;
```